# Strange behavior using TextAppearanceSpan on Kindle Fire

Tags: android, kindle, kindle-fire

Kindle Fire seems to have a 'different' way of handling spans in the SpannableStringBuilder. I found that when I add a TextAppearanceSpan *before* a ForegroundColorSpan the foreground color is ignored. If I add the TextAppearanceSpan first, then the ForegroundColorSpan it works fine. I have not seen this behavior on other Gingerbread devices, nor on Honeycomb devices...

FAILS:

```
        String text = "Styled with TextAppearanceSpan then ForegroundColor";
        int textLen = text.length();
        CharSequence styledText = "";
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        ssb.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 32, null, null), 0, textLen, 0);
        ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0000), 0, textLen, 0);

        styledText = TextUtils.concat(styledText, ssb);
        tv2.setText(styledText);
```

WORKS:

```
        String text = "Styled with ForegroundColor then TextAppearanceSpan";
        int textLen = text.length();    
        CharSequence styledText = "";
        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFFF0000), 0, textLen, 0);
        ssb.setSpan(new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 32, null, null), 0, textLen, 0);

        styledText = TextUtils.concat(styledText, ssb);
        tv1.setText(styledText);
```

Has anyone else seen this, or seen docs that describe rules for adding spans???

Thanks, - marc

Comment: I just discovered another annoying little glitch in the Kindle Fire's text rendering...  If you specify a BackgroundColorSpan and a ForegroundColorSpan in the same text run, the background color is ignored and the foreground color is used for both foreground and background.  So, if you want a yellow background with black text, you get a black background with black text, not so useful...